# Monitor "out of range" error when entering Windows 7 safe mode

Tags: windows-7, safe-mode, display-settings

I have a working Windows 7 Professional installation on my computer that seems to be working properly.

There are some changes I'd like to make to the system with an administrator account, and my system administrator account is currently deactivated. Historically, I can re-activate my administrator account by going into safe mode.

However, when I tried to enter safe mode via the F8 method, my display goes blank and shows an "out of range" error, this remains true even when I try it with a *different* monitor. The strange thing is if I boot into Windows normally, I experience no display problems, Device Manager does not show a problem with my display adapter, and the driver appears to have been installed correctly.

This is frustrating because I am currently locked out of all administrative functions on my computer because I can't activate the administrator account via safe mode. I also can't use the 640x480 mode because that does not give me administrative privileges to activate my administrator account.....

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unlock your admin account(s) with a LINUX booter, there are too many to choose from and well capable of rebooting your PC into a LINUX enviro with menus to reset, unlock and open up the high privs you seek instead of troubleshooting a non bootable safe mode.

You are attempting privilege escalation, w/o presumption nor accusations you're violating someone else's security, you can accomplish this but you're ill equipped to start troubleshooting un unbootable box in the manner you prefer to make the changes you're unwilling and or unable to describe for reasons uniquely and privately your own.

Go forth jedi.

Answer (score 1):

When a monitor displays "out of range", it means that the graphics card isn't giving the monitor something it can display. Many graphics cards require software that doesn't start in Safe Mode to run properly. Remove any additional graphics cards and plug into the onboard graphics port, then attempt to start in Safe Mode.